# Finding the EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 DigestAlgorithm field in the x509 certificate

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509, asn1

From the RFC - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt

**A.2.4 RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5**

For each OID, the parameters field associated with this OID in
   a value of type AlgorithmIdentifier shall have a value of type NULL.
   The OID should be chosen in accordance with the following table:

```
  Hash algorithm   OID
  --------------------------------------------------------
  MD2              md2WithRSAEncryption    ::= {pkcs-1 2}
  MD5              md5WithRSAEncryption    ::= {pkcs-1 4}
  SHA-1            sha1WithRSAEncryption   ::= {pkcs-1 5}
  SHA-256          sha256WithRSAEncryption ::= {pkcs-1 11}
  SHA-384          sha384WithRSAEncryption ::= {pkcs-1 12}
  SHA-512          sha512WithRSAEncryption ::= {pkcs-1 13}
```

When I run `open asn1parse` on a certificate, I can find this field

```
  984:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
  995:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  997:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: BIT STRING
```

However, there is also a DigestAlgorithm field in the RFC appendix

The EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding method includes an ASN.1 value of type
   DigestInfo, where the type DigestInfo has the syntax

```
  DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
      digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithm,
      digest OCTET STRING
  }
```

digestAlgorithm identifies the hash function and shall be an
   algorithm ID with an OID in the set PKCS1-v1-5DigestAlgorithms.  For
   a discussion of supported hash functions, see Appendix B.1.

```
  DigestAlgorithm ::=
      AlgorithmIdentifier { {PKCS1-v1-5DigestAlgorithms} }

  PKCS1-v1-5DigestAlgorithms    ALGORITHM-IDENTIFIER ::= {
      { OID id-md2 PARAMETERS NULL    }|
      { OID id-md5 PARAMETERS NULL    }|
      { OID id-sha1 PARAMETERS NULL   }|
      { OID id-sha256 PARAMETERS NULL }|
      { OID id-sha384 PARAMETERS NULL }|
      { OID id-sha512 PARAMETERS NULL }
```

How do I locate this parameter using openssl asn1parse or any other tool or utility?